# Bookmark last non-empty line that placed before a specific line

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need a notepad++ regex that bookmark last non-empty line that placed before a specific line.
for example if my list is this:

```
Word1
Word 2
Word 3$
Word45

fghjyh

Q1

/////////////////////////

Commando1

Commando 43
Doctor##

44GGTT45

TTTTTT

QQQWW22
/////////////////////////
```

regex must bookmark following lines:

```
Q1
QQQWW22
```

I tried following regex but not working:

```
^.+\S.+(?=^/{23}/)
```

how to fix this? where is my regex problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^\h*\S.*(?=\R+/{24})
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of a line
- `\h*` - zero or more horizonatal whitespaces
- `\S` - a non-whitespace char
- `.*` - the rest of the line
- `(?=\R+/{24})` - immediately to the right of the current location, there must be one or more line breaks (`\R+`) and then 24 slashes.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lBX2mk/1).

Screenshot:

[image]